# Why Visio suggest 4 position of multiplicity when using "Show multiplicity" on a relation with "Database UML notation" shapeset

Tags: database, uml, visio

As stated in the title when i use MS Visio to modelize my Database whith "Database UML annotations" (not sure about the traduction, in my french version it's "Notation de base de données UML") and when i put a relation and hit the button "Show multiplicity" Visio suggets me four position of digits, One over the relation on the left, one below and two others with the same pattern on the right (M1,M2, M3 & M4).

I've never seen this kind of representation in the different lessons that i read or in the posts that i read on this site. There are always only two positions, one on the left, one on the right.

Is there something that i've not understood about the UML representation ? Is this just a commodity of Visio which let us choose and delete the unused position ?

Many thanks for your advices.

Tom,

(P.S : if somenone can tell me if the term "Shapeset" that i use in the title is correct ;-) thanks you !)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Vision (well) and it's not an UML modeling but a general drawing tool. Since it has no semantics except showing graphical elements it suggests the "important" locations of connectors, namely both sides at both ends. That's where you place role names and multiplicities. The UML spec itself does not enforce any specific place. It's just talking about "near" (if at all) and you can only look at example diagrams for conventions. Probably Visio is taking that too serious (and graphic oriented) and offers just 4 fixed locations.

Comment: it's also what I thought, thanks for your answer. I wait for more answers in case someone has a different opinion and then I close the subject.

Comment: moreover, can you confirm that there are no other cases (in this context of UML database modeling) or we would need these 4 annotations over a relationship ? thanks

Comment: Basically that's it. However, a central position for the connector name and or stereotype is also foreseen (what ever central my meant; it's somewhere along in the path more or less in the middle).